# jQuery won't submit a form

Tags: jquery, forms

```
<!-- /Search box -->
<aside class="vehicle-search">
    <header>
        <h2>Find your vehicle</h2>
    </header>

    <article>
        <script>
            jQuery(function() {
                jQuery('.go').click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    jQuery('#vehicle').submit(function (event){
                        var action = '';
                        var actionid = jQuery('#categoryid').children(':selected').attr('value');

                        if (actionid == 1) {
                            action = 'sales/new-motorhomes';
                        }
                        if (actionid == 2) {
                            action = 'sales/used-motorhomes';
                        }
                        if (actionid == 3) {
                            action = 'sales/caravans';
                        }
                        jQuery(this).attr('action', action);
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
        <form id="vehicle" action="sales/new-motorhomes" method="post">
            <h3>Manufacturer</h3>
            <!-- <input type="submit"> -->
            <select name="manufacturer" id="manufacturers">
                <option value="1">Auto-Trail</option>
                <option value="2">Adria</option>
                <option value="3">Elddis</option>
            </select>

            <h3>Vehicle Type</h3>
            <select name="category" id="categoryid">
                <option value="1">New Motorhomes</option>
                <option value="2">Used Motorhomes</option>
                <option value="3">Caravans</option>
            </select>

            <h3>Berths</h3>
            <input type="text" name="berth" id="berths" style="border: 0; color: #f6931f; font-weight: bold;" />
            <div id="slider-berths"></div> 
        </form>
    </article>

    <footer>
        <span class="goButton">
            <a class="go" href=""></a>
        </span> 
    </footer>
</aside>
<!-- /Search box -->
```

What have I missed here..?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15246158/1250044

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `submit`-event is just declared but never called you have to put the `submit`-event outside of your `click`-handler and just trigger it on click:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/rvx27/

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('form:first').submit(function (event) {
        var action = '';
        var actionid = jQuery('#categoryid').children(':selected').attr('value');

        if (actionid == 1) {
            action = 'sales/new-motorhomes';
        }
        if (actionid == 2) {
            action = 'sales/used-motorhomes';
        }
        if (actionid == 3) {
            action = 'sales/caravans';
        }
        jQuery(this).attr('action', action);

    });
    jQuery('.go').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery('form:first').submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: This does work but Kami has given a more explanatory answer. I'll check back to see if this Answer is edited and if not he gets it :)

Comment: @SMacFadyen I added a bit... I've to say that Kami has stolen the code from my answer and provided a bit more explanatory on it (compare the answer times)... However I'm not here to collect points, I'm here to help ;)

Answer (score 1):

The code

```
jQuery('form:first').submit(function (event){});
```

Will assign an event handler to be called when the form is submitted. **It does no actually submit the form.**

To submit the form you must call

```
jQuery('form:first').submit();
```

or have a submit button in the form.

Your code could be rewritted as

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery('form:first').submit(function (event){
        var action = '';
        var actionid = jQuery('#categoryid').children(':selected').attr('value');

        if (actionid == 1) {
           action = 'sales/new-motorhomes';
        }
        if (actionid == 2) {
           action = 'sales/used-motorhomes';
        }
        if (actionid == 3) {
           action = 'sales/caravans';
        }
        jQuery(this).attr('action', action);

        return true; // Important to return okay to submit

   });

   jQuery('.go').click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       jQuery('form:first').submit(); // Trigger the submission
   });
});
```

This code assigns the event handler `document.ready()` event and then the subsequent click triggers the submit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use form id when you submit form using jquery.

**Replace** `jQuery('form:first').submit(function (event){`

**With** `jQuery('#vehicle').submit(function (event){`

Answer (score 0):

why aren't you using id selector

```
jQuery('#vehicle').submit();
```

this is faster and better than `:first` and should submit the form..

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
jQuery('form:first').submit(function (event){ ... });
```

...is binding a submit handler. To submit the form you need:

```
jQuery('form:first').submit();
```

If the only way the form can be submitted is via that link you can do that action setting stuff directly within the link's click handler before calling `.submit()` on the form. Or bind the submit handler separately (from outside the click handler or it'll keep binding additional handlers on each click) and then just call `.submit()` from within the click handler.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jQuery(function() {

            jQuery('.go').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var action = '';
                var actionid = jQuery('#categoryid').children(':selected').attr('value');

                if (actionid == 1) {
                    action = 'sales/new-motorhomes';
                }
                if (actionid == 2) {
                    action = 'sales/used-motorhomes';
                }
                if (actionid == 3) {
                    action = 'sales/caravans';
                }
                jQuery('form:first').attr('action', action);

                jQuery('form:first').submit()

                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: Bad answer, you kill the default `submit` behavior through this! ;)